# We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, sandbox

I'm getting this error on a sandbox account:

> We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please go back to the merchant and try using a different payment method.

My .Net app is successfully redirecting to PayPal, with the correct payment details. As soon as I log in with my sandbox account I get the above error. Is there a way to get to a log or anything that could help me source the issue? It was all working fine until this week, so I wonder has something changed in that time?

I have checked the accounts have a suitable balance. The payment is for €24 so it is not excessive. There are a few other posts regarding the issue but nothing with any suitable suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

After about 4 hours at this today I finally have success. I logged in to sandbox.paypal.com with the sandbox facilitator details, and updated a bunch of settings in the `Profile > My Selling Tools > Block Payments` page. You may need to upgrade to a business account in order to see those settings.

I basically set it to allow almost anything in there, and hey presto... the next 2 payment tests worked.

Comment: I can't tell you how long I spent trying to solve this.  This issue makes me upset that Paypal Can't document this, or can't be setup a sandbox account with all these by default set to accept all. 
At least they can give use error messages. 
 The amount of people complaining about this issue on google and PP's community forums should justify them sorting it out. 
In todays day and age where there is logging and analytics I can't believe, that this problem hasn't appeared on Paypals radar.  

This is the reason so many people are looking to other tools and its so easy to fix.

Comment: i have the same issue but i can't find Profile > Payment Receiving Preferences page. in my test account

Comment: sger: I had updated the facilitator account to Business Plus (log in to the sandbox developer account and update the facilitator acocunt details). This opens up more options, when you log in as the facilitator to sandbox.paypal.com, under Profile you should see the Payment Receiving Preferences option.

Comment: @MobileBloke I can't wait to migrate to another payment gateway. at the moment too busy. They are not even the cheapeast

Comment: This solution worked for me. If you're reading this and don't see Payment Receiving Preferences even after upgrading to a Business Pro account because you have the new PayPal UI then go to: **Block payments** from your **Profile**. You'll then be sent to the old PayPal UI which _is_ called Payment Receiving Preferences.

Comment: For me when i going on login page loged in to my account it doesnt give me sandbox personal account id, password it says "Something went wrong. One or more sandbox accounts could not be fetched. Try again."

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer to this will likely vary from one period to another, depending on what problems PayPal are experiencing.

This error message appeared out of nowhere for me today, in the Sandbox. The only way I've found to work around it has been to log on to [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com), go to Sandbox > Accounts, and create a new buyer account.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what the problem was for me.

Both of my sandbox accounts have their currencies set to INR. The client website receives payments in USD. So I was getting this error.

I created a new buyer sandbox account and set the country to US (not sure how to edit currencies in an existing account). After this the payment went through successfully.

Paypal really needs to document this better.

Answer (score 3):

This error also came because of PayPal account location 
Like I am using my personal account which is created in India and I am using its "Client_ID" and "Client_Secret" for the transaction but it showing me this error
so after reading whole documentation of PayPal, 
I get to know that 
you cannot use Indian account for PayPal payment integration. so I use one of my friend accounts, which were created in the US and I used its "Client_ID" and "Client_Secret"
and my error is gone 
So guys please there also in your code.

Answer (score 2):

create a buyer account on SandBox And try again.

### Go to SandBox Account And Create a New Account under the Account Section

For me , I just create a Buyer Account So it Works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue when i was using below link

```
 header('location:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
```

but i had changed that code as below.

```
 header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'.$querystring);
```

then it is working fine for me. Hope this may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just go : sandbox.paypal.com
My Profile->Selling tools->Block payments->Block accidental payments:(check)No, allow multiple payments per invoice ID

Answer (score 0):

The currency mentioned in your node.js app should be the same as of the country that you mentioned in your PayPal account.
for eg:If your country is India then in your node.js app, currency:"INR".

Comment: How would you be able to receive US payments in USD if you add your currency in INR? does paypal take care of that automatically for international customers?
Paypal has given me the option to receive in USD as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

***it’s typically due to the currency settings in the vendor’s/merchant PayPal account. The reason for this message coming up is typically due to seller's/merchant's setting your PayPal to support the currency you have your product set at the time checkout***

> How can we resolve this?

------ **For sandbox Account** -------

```
Simply create a sandbox business seller account following by creating a new app for 
that seller and select country exactly the same to the currency which a buyer will
 purchase with currency.
```

------ **For live Account** -------

```
1 => Login to your business account
2 => Select Financial Information
3 => Currency Management
There you can add any number of currency for which you want to accept payment from the buyer currency.
```

[Reference](https://support.thrivecart.com/help/paypal-unable-to-process-payment-message/)

Hopefully, this can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How I Solved it ( if you're testing it on sandbox create a merchant account of the US origin if in case you're sending money in Dollars same may apply for other currencies as well , this does not apply for merchant accounts )